# Samba AD DC beginner questions(add user differences, user rights)

Tags: samba4

I have a Samba AD DC I'm setting up, and I have a bunch of smallish questions.

Adding users: It looks like there are three ways:

```
samba-tool user add USERNAME
pdbedit -a USERNAME
smbpasswd -a USERNAME
```

or, do some fancy things to link samba users and unix users. (as shown [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba_domain_controller))

What are the differences between those?

Is it possible to have some(not all) samba users linked to unix users, and keep passwords synched?

Roaming profiles: I set it up according to [the samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_Windows_Profiles#Profile_share_with_using_POSIX_ACLs), but I need to modify each account with `pdbedit -U username -p \\\\parabox\\profile\\%USERNAME%`(parabox is the test domain box). Am I missing something about account creation, or is this expected?

I haven't done any research into this one at all, so feel free to ignore it, but how to setup policies.

Many thanks for any help, or links to documentation that I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up with a lot later:

- On account creation, it doesn't seem to matter what method is used.
- On linked unix/samba users, I could not get it to work. I even did a clean install, but it was just too much effort; while it would be useful, I did not pursue it further.
- On roaming profiles, it seems you need to set it up for each account manually.